# How to Combine Multipe AND and ORs in SSRS Expression?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics

I have been trying to tackle this one for a while now, but I cannot get it humming along.   I have reviewed a number of questions here, but no one has  the exact issue I am having.  So, I am hopeful someone here can help.

I have a query, which runs perfectly in SSMS.  But, this query is to be fed to a report.  The report has 2 parameters, Start Date and End Date, that are supplied by the user at runtime.  I need to do a series of checks against these dates, and only pull back records that meet one of multiple criteria, hence the OR.

I wanted to do this in Filters, and just add one filter for each condition.  However, the default behavior between filters is AND, and I need to perform an OR between my complex filters.  So I found an example online, and started typing away.

The expressions on either side of the OR, work when standing alone. However, as soon as I combine them with the OR operator, I am only returning the records that match the front side (before the OR) of the OR, but the records that match the back side (after the OR) are not included.

This is a report for Dynamics CRM 2015, and I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Here is a screenshot of the Filter I have put on the report:
[image: Screenshot of Filter]

Here is the Expression inside this filter:

```
=((Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value <> Nothing) AND (Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value >= Parameters!StartDate.Value) AND (Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value)) Or ((Fields!xyz_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <> Nothing)  AND  (Fields!xyz_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <= Parameters!StartDate.Value) AND (Fields!xyz_GraduationDate.Value <> Nothing) AND (Fields!xyz_GraduationDate.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value))
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why my OR doesn't work on both ends of the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS expressions don't like Boolean logic. You would need to use an IIF:

```
=IIF((Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value <> Nothing) 
  AND (Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value >= Parameters!StartDate.Value) 
  AND (Fields!xyz_StartDateNewStudent.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value)) 
Or ((Fields!xyz_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <> Nothing)  
  AND  (Fields!xyz_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <= Parameters!StartDate.Value) 
  AND (Fields!xyz_GraduationDate.Value <> Nothing) 
  AND (Fields!xyz_GraduationDate.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value))
, True, False)
```

Comment: Thanks, Hannover!  After playing a little bit with the code (misplaced parenthesis), and then making sure I was entering a date range that would satisfy both of my requirements, I believe I have this thing firing as expected.

Comment: Filter Expr:

'=IIF((Fields!mids_StartDateNewStudent.Value <> Nothing) 
  AND (Fields!mids_StartDateNewStudent.Value >= Parameters!StartDate.Value) 
  AND (Fields!mids_StartDateNewStudent.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value) 
Or 
((Fields!mids_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <> Nothing)  
  AND (Fields!mids_StartDateCarryoverStudent.Value <= Parameters!StartDate.Value) 
  AND (Fields!mids_GraduationDate.Value <> Nothing) 
  AND (Fields!mids_GraduationDate.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value))
 , True, False)'

Comment: Just thinking - is this working right? `Fields!mids_GraduationDate.Value <> Nothing`. I seem to remember something about NOTHING not working in a comparison and you would need to use `NOT ISNOTHING(Fields!mids_GraduationDate.Value)` instead. Check your results if you are missing something.

Comment: Yeah it is, though I am not 100% sure if it is the <> Nothing thats actually filtering them.  In SQL, of course, null values are already omitted from a query like this.  For whatever reason, I had to throw it in for the 'second side' of my original OR  statement, or it would pull in all the NULLS.  That may have been more of a product of SSRS not liking the boolean expression I was using.  I will remove the <> Nothing from the report on Monday and see what it does and let you knkow.  I did see the isNothing function, but was trying to prove the filter worked without added parenthesis :D

Comment: I should add, the report itself only pulls back 5 total records at this time, so thats how I can quickly say that the NULL results are indeed being filtered out.  I was very surprised when I had to include the <> Nothing in the second half of my OR, but that indeed did filter the NULLs, even while using Boolean  filter (without OR).  I hope this helps you, and I will still plan on pulling out the <> Nothing on Monday to see if it still fires properly.  I like to have everything run as efficiently as possible.  Thanks again for your help.